# Mosaico 2.9 - Templates: cannot edit existing templates after update

Tags: mosaico

After updating from 2.8 to 2.9 in my sandbox (and updating all URLs in Mosaico tables as a result of site URL change), I notice that the interface to edit existing templates isn't really usable.

Here's what it looked like in 2.8

[image]

And here's what it looks like after update to 2.9:

[image]

So with 2.9, this new interface doesn't allow me to edit the templates -- nor can I change the template settings....

Any suggestions on how to resolve?

Comment: What version of CiviCRM, Afform, Search Kit, FlexMailer are you running?

Comment: CiviCRM 5.48.0
Afform: Core Runtime v 0.5
Search Kit 1.0 beta3
FlexMailer 1.1.2

Comment: Correction: FlexMailer version is the core version : 5.48.0

Comment: I have updated a few client sites in my sandbox and they all seem to experience this issue. Am I alone in this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I'm providing an update in case anyone else has this issue.
The issue was that /wp-content/**uploads**/civicrm/ext
contained:

Afform: Core Runtime v 0.5
Search Kit 1.0 beta3

And civiCRM was picking up these two extensions instead of the core versions found at:
/wp-content/**plugins**/civicrm/ext

Form Core 5.48.0
Search Kit 5.48.0

To resolve the issue, I:

1. Disabled Mosaico
2. Disabled the Afform extension and deleted the folder /wp-content/**uploads**/civicrm/ext/Afform, did a Extension Refresh, so it found the core version, enabled it and ran the associated database update.
3. Disabled Search Kit and deleted the folder /wp-content/**uploads**/civicrm/ext/SearchKit, , did a Extension Refresh, so it found the core version, enabled it and ran the associated database update.
4. Re-enabled Mosaico

And I was then able to edit the Mosaico templates successfully.